# How to remove s-maxage header from asp.net mvc response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cache-control

By default, Asp.Net MVC (at least my setup) seems to send a header with the value

```
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
```

I need to remove the s-maxage=0 part. The reason is that IE6 seems to handle the content-disposition: attachment header wrong if this header is present.

The end effect I observe is that if the user chooses to Open the downloaded file instead of saving it, it is not actually saved. The difference between the working non-mvc version and the non-working mvc version is just this header.

Working response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
Date: Thu, 10 Feb 2011 19:35:47 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=results.txt
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 210
Connection: Close

<<DATA>>
```

Non-working response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
Date: Thu, 10 Feb 2011 20:24:04 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=results.txt
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 90
Connection: Close

<<DATA>>
```

Comment: Not your answer but if you set `no-cache` there is no `s-maxage`. `[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]`

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: Sorry, don't remember, this was almost 10 years ago